# linearizing a tree to an array and answering "sum" queries on paths

Tags: algorithm, tree, fenwick-tree

The question is motivated by the [travtree](https://www.codechef.com/problems/TRAVTREE) problem in codechef. In the [editorial](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/82587/travtree-editorial) they recommend linearizing the tree to an array by recording for each node its discovery and exit times in a `DFS` traversal. Now we can quickly answer queries about `sum subtree` - by summing events that happened in the segment `[discovery time, exit time]` of that node. (we are using a `Fenwick` tree to answer these queries fast).

HOWEVER, to solve that problem we also need to quickly answer `sum path` queries. That is - summing events that happened along the shortest path between `a, b`. How is that possible? The answer they give is this:

For each interesting event they update this:

```
    update(BT2,event_node,1);
    update(BT2,out[event_node],-1);
```

and the `sum path(a,b)` is now this:

```
    int l = lca(a,b);
    ans = query(BT2,a) + query(BT2,b) - query(BT2,l) -  (l==1  ? 0 : query(BT2, parent[0][l]));
```

Where `query` is the prefix sum. How is that correct?? when you look at the prefix sum till `a` you might encounter lots of nodes which are irrelevant to the path between `l` and `a`!

Answer (score 0):

In order to linearize a `sum path` query - sum of events that happened on the shortest path between tree nodes `a, b` we indeed have to do the following:

When an event happens in node `v`, we `update(IN[v], 1)` and `update(OUT[v], -1)`. `IN` being the node's DFS `discovery time` and `OUT` the DFS `exit time`.

Now the query would be `query(IN[b]) - query(IN[a]-1)`. The `query(IN[b])` is a prefix sum: it starts from the root, and traverses the tree until it reaches `b`. Note that for each node `v` we will pass *not on the direct path* from root to `b`, we will discover and then eventually exit it. Only for the nodes *on the path* we will discover and *not* exit. Because of the way we updated, this means that we will effectively sum the nodes on the path `root, b` (including `b`).

Now its clear that the same happens in `query(IN[a]-1)` - it is the sum of the nodes on the path `root, a` (not including `a` this time). Subtracting them gives us `a, b`. Draw a sketch and you'll see it for yourselves.

---

For completeness - the method for `sum subtree` is different both in `update` and in `query`. For each event you only `update(IN[v])`. Now for querying `sum subtree(a)` we do `query(OUT[a]) - query(IN[a]-1)`. This time in `query(OUT[a])` we sum all nodes we traversed until we discover `a`, and then all nodes in `a`'s subtree until we exit it. Now we subtract `query(IN[a] - 1)` - all the nodes until we discover `a`. We're left exactly with only the `a` subtree.